# Export AS400 database tables into flat files using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ibm-midrange, flat-file

I need to transfer around 7 databases in AS400 to text format using SSIS, each DB has over 200 tables, and from on of the DB, I have to get specific tables(about 300).

Any suggestions on how to implement it?

Comment: I would look into BiML.  I'm not sure how well it works with AS400 databases.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM i has it's own utilities to copy data from a table to a stream file.

[Copy To Import File (CPYTOIMPF)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/cpytoimpf.htm) command on the IBM i.

Comment: I need to implement it through SSIS.